# Access protected members from templated (static) member function

Tags: c++, templates

Ok so I'm taking a sort of modified [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) route here to avoid virtual function look-ups. But I just can't understand one error it gives me...

So I'm trying to translate:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void foo(A *pA)
    {
        pA->bar();
    }

protected:
    virtual void bar()
    {
        TRACE0(_T("A::bar\n"));
    }
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    virtual void bar()
    {
        TRACE0(_T("B::bar\n"));
    }
};
```

which works as expected to:

```
class A
{
public:
    template <class T>
    static void foo(T *pT)
    {
        pT->bar();
    }

protected:
    void bar()
    {
        TRACE0(_T("A::bar\n"));
    }
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    void bar()
    {
        TRACE0(_T("B::bar\n"));
    }
};
```

which gives the error:

```
error C2248: 'B::bar' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'B'
see declaration of 'B::bar'
see declaration of 'B'
see reference to function template instantiation 'void A::foo<B>(T *)' 
being compiled with
[
    T=B
]
```

Now I know, this is easily fixed by adding `friend class A;` to class B, but that's not very neat. Isn't there another way?

EDIT: Example usage:

```
B b;
b.foo<B>(&b);
```

EDIT #2: The member function `foo` being static doesn't matter I noticed.

Comment: I think this happens because parent classes don't have special access to protected members of childern (do they?). It only works for children to have access to parents.

Comment: As Zan said, a parent class can't access the protected members of a derived class (unless it's a friend of course)

Comment: Sounds about right... `A::foo` is trying to call `B::bar` and failing because its protected. `friend class A` sounds like the proper solution.

Comment: So in the first case it only appears that the parent has access to the protected members of a derived class because it is calling a virtual function (of it's own class) and that function is 'looking up' to derived classes?

Comment: Yes it works because it's a virtual function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case `bar` is virtual function and `foo` accesses it through a pointer to `A` thus invoking the function pointer and the specified index of Vtable as layout'ed by class `A`. Thus it works.

However, in second case, `A::foo` explicitly calls the non-virtual function from different class it has no access to. `B::bar` is not a virtual overload of `A::bar` - it is completely different unrelated function.

Therefore, making `friend class A;` is the neatest you can get, I am afraid.